# IE8 (compatibility mode) won't load my Ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, compatibility-mode

I am working on a jQuery script on http://www.qxl.dk/ and I can't seem to get IE7 (or more accurately, IE8 in IE7 compatibility mode) to load my content.

The sidebar box on the right named "QXL Aktuelt" loads its HTML content from an external file using Ajax `load()`, then triggers a custom jQuery event ("`aktuelt_loaded`") that starts a carousel script (like a scrolling newsticker).

Several other content sections on the same page are loaded through Ajax and they work just fine, so I'm wondering what's going wrong. Everything works as expected in Firefox 3.6 and IE8, but not in IE8's compatibility mode.

The script that loads the Ajax content is (inline on the page):

```
<div id="qxlaktueltHolder"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#qxlaktueltHolder").load("/contents/dk/modul/qxlaktuelt/qxlaktuelt.htm", function() {
        $("#qxlaktueltHolder").trigger("qxlaktuelt_loaded", []);
    });
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.qxl.dk/contents/dk/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.qxl.dk/contents/dk/js/qxlaktuelt_liveload.js'></script>
```

The external script that responds to the event is in the following file:

http://www.qxl.dk/contents/dk/js/qxlaktuelt_liveload.js

All ideas are very welcome.

Comment: There's a `language` attribute in one of your script tags. It's [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1).

Comment: @Marcel: True - but that shouldn't affect the ajax load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Looks like your content is being loaded. You seem to have a CSS display issue. Using IE's developer tools, I searched for the href of an `a` that was loaded properly in Safari

`http://www.123hjemmeside.dk/pages/receive.aspx?target=wl&partnerkey=dkqxl:Hobby_aktuelt_1`

and found that is was on the page along with all the other content.

**UPDATE:**

The problem is with your `#newsticker` element. It, and all of its `li` elements, have height and/or width properties set to `0`.

So whatever code is responsible for sizing/displaying the `#newsticker` and its content seems to be the culpret.

---

This is a guess, but this script `qxlaktuelt_liveload.js` is being loaded after this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#qxlaktueltHolder").load("/contents/dk/modul/qxlaktuelt/qxlaktuelt.htm", function() {
        $("#qxlaktueltHolder").trigger("qxlaktuelt_loaded", []);
    });
</script>
```

So depending on how long the `load()` takes, the script may or may not be loaded.

Try:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.qxl.dk/contents/dk/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.qxl.dk/contents/dk/js/qxlaktuelt_liveload.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#qxlaktueltHolder").load("/contents/dk/modul/qxlaktuelt/qxlaktuelt.htm", function() {
        $("#qxlaktueltHolder").trigger("qxlaktuelt_loaded", []);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Actually, that shouldn't be a problem - at least it isn't in IE8 or Firefox (I've tested using delays etc. and the event model I use works regardless of what is loaded first, the script or the Ajax content).
But on the other hand, compatibility mode tends to make up its own rules as it goes along, so I'll give it a try. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Jens Roland - Yeah, `load()` being asynchronous, I sort of figured that `qxlaktuelt_liveload.js` might have a chance to load before the response came back. Although, if the response was fast enough, there would be an issue, so it is better practice to load your script files in proper order, so that you're not referencing code in a file that hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: @Jens Roland - Looks to me like your content is being loaded. It appears to be a CSS display issue. I copied the `href` of an element that was loaded in Safari, and did a search for it in the developer tools in IE. Sure enough, it was there, along with all the others. I'll update my answer to reflect the fact, and will try to see if I can find a quick resolution to the CSS issue.

Comment: Interesting!!!! Thanks a bunch - that narrows it down a lot! The code that displays the LI items is in the jCarousel file, and I'll try delaying that until window.load - that could be it :)

Comment: Window.load worked - yay! Thanks for the help, I am marking your answer as correct. Well done!!

Answer (score -3):

Remove all the console in your JavaScript code. For some reason, the IE's break with this.