# jQuery .find() not returning value when IE in Compatability mode

Tags: jquery, ie-compatibility-mode

I am using an ajax call to fetch details in XML format. datatype is set as XML in jquery.ajax.

Output ajax response is

```
<FilterData>
    <DataValue>
        <text>1</text>
        <text>2</text>
        <text>3</text>
    </DataValue>
</FilterData>
```

`responseXML` variable is having the response from jquery ajax.

```
var response = $(responseXML).find("DataValue");
```

`response.length is > 0` when IE is not in compatability mode. But it is 0 when the page is in compatability mode.

> I am looking for a way in which I don't have to forcefully change the
>   browser mode.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753758/ie-compatibility-mode-forced-in-ajax-code Suggestion 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921955/ie8-compatibility-mode-wont-load-my-ajax-content Suggestion 3: http://jwcooney.com/2011/12/05/internet-explorer-compatibility-mode-breaks-jquery/

Comment: Are the above mentioned questions anyway related to this one?

Comment: yes. ajax + compatibility mode doesnt load data, give it some effort and google or search SO. -1

Comment: I am sure that data is getting returned after the ajax call, but the problem is that I am not able to extract details from that.

Comment: your js is wrong (but originally your question was about the compatbility mode, what is it now? access problem or IE problem??)
are you trying to save the complete array text 1-3 or are you trying to get value 1 2 and 3 ... you can use functions like .text(); ... e.g. like var riable = $(this).find("text").text();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier the data returned was in XML format. Now changed it to json and it works fine.

Thanks,
Rahul